# Exponential of matrix and its inverse

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Φ(t) = \begin{bmatrix}e^{-2t}*cos(t)&-sin(t) \\e^{-2t}*sin(t) &cos(t)\end{bmatrix} is a fundamental matrix solution of the nonautonomous linear system
**x'**(t) = A(t)**x** with A(t) = \begin{bmatrix}−2 cos^2
t&-1-sin2t\\1-sin2t &-2sin^2t\end{bmatrix} So, fundemental matrix can be written as 
Φ(t) = $e^{At}$ So its inverse can be written as $Φ(t)^{-1}$ = $e^{-At}$ = $e^{A(-t)}$ = Φ(-t)  So Φ(-t) = \begin{bmatrix}e^{2t}*cos(t)&sin(t) \\-e^{2t}*sin(t) &cos(t)\end{bmatrix}--------------(1)  but inverse of 2*2 matrix A = \begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}is $A^{-1}$ = 1/(ad-bc)*\begin{bmatrix}d&-b\\-c&a\end{bmatrix} by this calculation inverse of fundemental matrix is $Φ(t)^{-1}$ = \begin{bmatrix}e^{2t}*cos(t)&e^{2t}sin(t) \\-sin(t) &cos(t)\end{bmatrix} but this is not equal to (1) how can this be done and which is correct?

Comment: You can write the fundamental solution as $e^{tA}$ only if $A$ is time-invariant. But the present $A(t)$ is time-variant.

Comment: Why is $-A(t)=A(-t)$?

Comment: @N.S. OP wrote $-At = A(-t)$, assuming that $A$ is constant (which is of course not true here).

Comment: Why we can't write I mean what is the reason for that

Comment: @YASHWANTHM Just Calculate $A(-t)$ and $-A(t)$ and compare

Comment: But in question above $e^{(-1)*A*t}$ = $e^{A*(-t)}$

Comment: As amsmath noticed, the problem occurs already in the line below the second display: **No, the fundamental matrix  needn't be equal to $\exp(tA(t))$, nor to $\exp(\int_{t_0}^t A(s)\,\mathrm{d}s)$.** And from the false statement you can conclude anything.